# How to save Whatsapp voicenotes to Computer?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, audio, voice-recording

I am connecting my Android phone to my computer trying to save Whatsapp voicenotes in my computer. But when I open the folder `WhatsApp Voice Notes` it is blank. I can see the files (begin with PTT) in my Android but it seems they can't be read on my Computer. Previously they could. Is anyone having the same issues or have some solution for it?

Comment: "it seems it can't be read" what actually happens if you try?

Comment: this may be useful: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/102512/how-to-transfer-whatsapp-audio-files-to-computer?rq=1

Comment: Hi @AADTechnical thanks for your comment, I have fixed my issue by sending it through email ^_^

Answer (score 1):

My problem has been solved. I tried this trick and it works.

1. Open the folder on your mobile. It is `WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Voice Notes/`
2. Select all files all any files you wanna copy to your computer
3. Attach them on email and send email to yourself
4. Now open your email on computer and download the attachments.

Tadaaaaa~~~ Now you have the files on your computer ^_^

NB. The files extension is `.optus`, if your media cannot play it, I suggest you download a optus-mp3 converter.

Hope this helps. Good luck!